# How to Remove Action Added by Plugin in WordPress to Change Priority

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to change the priority of the following line of code generated by a plugin.

```
        add_action( apply_filters( 'mv_grow_meta_tag_hook', 'wp_head' ), [ 'Mediavine\Grow\Meta_Tags', 'build_and_output' ], 1 );
```

And I want to replace it with this:

```
        add_action( apply_filters( 'mv_grow_meta_tag_hook', 'wp_head' ), [ 'Mediavine\Grow\Meta_Tags', 'build_and_output' ], 3 );
```

Do I first need to remove the action and then add action again but with a lower priority?

Comment: Yes. You must find the hook that this gets registered in and then use either a higher priority (preferred) or later hook to change it.